# How to deal with losing deep imports in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have just updated to `Angular 4` and learned that it no longer supports `deep imports`.

So I was using VALID to help validate forms. But now that the I can't import it with the `deep import`

```
import { VALID } from '@angular/forms/src/model
```

And since this does not work,

```
import { VALID } from '@angular/forms/'
```

What are we expected to do to access it? Or anything for that matter that was previously accessed with a `deep import`?

Answer (score 0):

`Angular 4`  no longer supports deep imports . In `Angular 2`  you could do this,

```
import { VALID } from '@angular/forms/src/model'
```

but now in `Angular 4`  you can only go to the first level,

```
import { VALID } from '@angular/forms'
```

So basically anything you were accessing by deep import is no longer useable if it is not exported, which would make it available so you can access it from that first level.

So in my case `VALID`  was not reachable. So in order to validate I just validated it with the string response from checking the validation of the input field on blur instead of the bool.

```
formInputValidate(inputField: string, ErrorTitle: string, ErrorMessage: string) {
  if (this.profileForm.get(inputField).status === 'VALID') {
    this.toastSuccess(inputField, ' entered correctly');
  } else {
    this.toastWarning(ErrorTitle, ErrorMessage);
  }
}
```

Which raises a new question,

In my case this was an easy fix. But if the situation is more complicated and the deep import  helper was critical, how do we get around this?

[I asked the contributors of Angular on git here and they said,](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15542#issuecomment-289671010)

[image]

So it appears that if there is someone we need we can request it and they will consider it!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
npm uninstall valid
```

Then

```
npm install valid
```