# What is a "deep import" in Angular 4 context?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know I have to remove all deep imports before upgrading to Angular 4, but I have no idea what is a deep import. Literally nobody mentions it. What is it? How does it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [How to deal with losing deep imports in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060615/how-to-deal-with-losing-deep-imports-in-angular-4#43097335), an example of a deep import:

```
import { VALID } from '@angular/forms/src/model'
```

meaning 3 levels deep, whereas now you can only go 1 level:

```
import { VALID } from '@angular/forms'
```

which is invalid if "VALID" is in `model`, 3 levels deep. that's all there is to it. If you need something that's in "deep", it should be exported to in the first level now, or you need to open a ticket to angular to export it.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to advertise my own gist article, but I explain them [here](https://gist.github.com/daleyjem/0f38f561a4e91e58eba580889f38330f)

### Description

A "deep import" is simply an ESM import that goes deeper than the package root:

```js
import thingA from 'my-package-name/src/components/thingA'
import thingB from '@my-namespace/my-package-name/src/components/thingA'
```

A namespaced package does not necessitate a deep import if the package name (`package.json:name` key) contains a slash:

```js
import thingA from '@my-namespace/my-package-name'
```

Relative imports (`./path/to/module`) are also not considered deep imports, in fact it might be considered bad practice to "shallow import" an exported module from one's own package by it's `package.json:main` key location (i.e. `src/index.js`) as this can often cause circular dependencies.

### Why deep imports can be a problem

#### Package bundling

Package bundlers are often used to transpile and condense a project to a distributive, single-file version (i.e. `dist/bundle.js`). Other packages that try to deep import from such packages experience errors, as the directory structure from `src` may often not be maintained or even included in the published package.

#### Unintended imports and directory changes

A developer might deep import a module from a package when it was not intended to be used outside of the scope of that package. Your changing of the name of an internally-used export or your package's directory structure should not require a major version (breaking change) update for a module that was only intended to be consumed internally.